# Spaces in file output in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am doing programming in Python with C Background:

Developing the Script to do some Automation Job.
I am writing data in to one file like below,

```
f.write("hallo") Output is : hallo
```

I want to give 4 spaces before writing.

I have tried these options:

```
f.write("    hallo")
f.write(""+""+""+""+"hallo")
```

But am not able to achieve what I want.

Comment: Those are empty strings. If you put a space between the quotation marks e.g. `" "` it would work. You could also do `"    hallo"`

Comment: Now that it's been edited I can see you already had `"    hallo"`. I see no reason why that wouldn't work. How are you viewing the output?

Comment: A standard and maintanable way would be `f.write((" " * 4) + "hallo")`

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments :

```
f.write((" " * 4) + "hallo")
```

This would be perfect.

Answer (score 2):

```
with open("demo.txt", "w") as f: # open file demo.txt in write mode
    f.write("    hallo")
```

Don't know what trouble you are getting but in this way you can get text file demo.txt written with four white spaces and hallo

*demo.txt*

```
    hallo
```

there are many way to achieve this i.e. let's say you want to print `Hello` with n number of whitespaces ahead of it:

```
v = " "*n + "Hello" #  '    Hello' (i have used n=4)
```

**Another example:**

```
spaces = " "*10  # 10 spaces
new_line = "\n"*2 # two new lines
string = "Hello"
final = spaces + new_line + string
with open("demo.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(final)
```

Note: if you reopen existing file in write mode it will clear all content of file and then starts writing content

Answer (score 0):

```
f.write("    hallo") # give manu
```

or

```
f.write(" " + " " + " " + " " + "hallo")
```